# multiple select send data two times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I'm creating a simple multiple selectable dropdown using jQuery [amsify](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/dropdown-search-box-amsify-select.html) Select

this is my User interface

[image]

this is my user inter face code

```
<label for="medium_id" class="col-form-label">Medium</label>
<select class="form-control " multiple="multiple" id="medium_id" name="medium_id[]">
<option value="">Select Medium</option>
    @foreach( [$medium][0] as $medium)
         <option value="{{$medium->id}}">{{$medium->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

this is my Laravel storing to database code

```
foreach ($request->medium_id as $medium)
{
    medium_classes::create([
         'classes_id'=>$classes->id,
         'medium_id'=>$medium
    ]);
}
```

this is my jQuery code

```
<script>
$('select').amsifySelect({
   type :'bootstrap',
   searchable : true
});
</script>
```

and this is dd() output in here that multiple select sending data's multiple times

[image]
any one can you help me

Comment: Just sure the <select> element generated by the plugin don't have duplicate value.

Comment: Anyway, I however have a quick hack. just apply the unique on the `$request->medium_id`. But we should find the real reason.

Comment: ya @SachinKumar finally i did like that, but i can't find real reason

Comment: check your select element when you click any of the options. by inspecting the element(in any browser dev tool) and sure the value is selected and no duplication.

Comment: yes using dev tool i remove name's `[]` this mark it's not duplicate

Comment: but when i change in code its not work @SachinKumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240813/discussion-between-gajarthan-thevarajah-and-sachin-kumar).

Comment: they are actually using <select> element which is hidden by default. i.e display: none, so just confirm there should be one <select> element and when you select any of the values the option will be selected. So you can get ideas from those elements.